# perl multiline find and replace

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, multiline

I'm trying to use a simple perl one-liner on the following input:

```
@F7##########0/1
C4CTA6GCAAC56G67CTCA99C
+
b[[WZ56W]87X9HBB
@44FC6%%%%&&&&&&&1UP1
GTS4HY2IOMD3FCCA8DFLLLTG
+
]]^4YY23ZV\6`a8`^9^a
```

etc.

I would like my output to look like:

```
@F7##########0/1
C4CTA6GCAAC56G67CTCA99C
+F7##########0/1
b[[WZ56W]87X9HBB
@44FC6%%%%&&&&&&&1UP1
GTS4HY2IOMD3FCCA8DFLLLTG
+44FC6%%%%&&&&&&&1UP1
]]^4YY23ZV\6`a8`^9^a
```

etc.

I'd like to search for a line starting with `@`, and storing (grouping) the remainder of the line in `$1`. I then find the next occurrence of `+` and add `$1` onto the end of that line.

I've tried `perl -pi -e "s%^@(.*)$\1\n(.*)$\2\n(\+)$\3\n%$1\n$2\n\+$1%mg" file.txt` but I can't seem to match anything after `^@(.*)$\1\n`.

Surely there's a working one-liner out there to accomplish this. `Awk` or `Sed` or `tr` one-liners are welcome, but changes to `file.txt` must be made in-line as the `file.txt` is large and writing to another file is undesirable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately `awk` does not offer in-line changes so it may be not what you need. But if you do then the following would work -

```
awk '/^@/{a=substr($0,2)}/^\+/{printf ("%s%s\n", $0,a);next}1' file > newfile
```

**Update:** I have made an attempt to do what you are looking for in **`sed`** which allows for `in-file` changes.

```
sed -i '/^@/{h};/^\+/{x;s/\(.\)\(.*\)/+\2/}' file
```

#### Explanation:

- **`/^@/{h}`** : We look for line that starts with `@` sign and when we find it, we put the entire line in `hold space`. `Sed` has two buffers, `pattern space` and `hold space`. `Pattern space` is where all the action takes place. `hold space` allows us to retain information temporarily so that we can do some action on it later on.
- **`/^\+/{x;...`** : When we find a line that starts with a `+`, we do `x` action on it. What it means is, we pull information out of our `hold space` and put it back in `pattern space`. Once we have done that, we do a simple substitution.
- **`...s/\(.\)\(.*\)/+\2/`** : What this means is we identify characters using `grouping`. Since our portion of text had `@` in front of it, which you didnt want, we isolate that character using `.` which means any character. We also put everything else of that line in a second group. These groups needs to be escaped {so you see \( \) instead of just ()}. In the replacement section we put in a `+` and the second group. Remember the first group captured only had `@` in it. We just want the second group so we reference it using `\2` (backslash and the number of group you wish to reference).

#### Test for `awk`:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
@F7##########0/1
C4CTA6GCAAC56G67CTCA99C
+
b[[WZ56W]87X9HBB
@44FC6%%%%&&&&&&&1UP1
GTS4HY2IOMD3FCCA8DFLLLTG
+
]]^4YY23ZV\6`a8`^9^a

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '/^@/{a=substr($0,2)}/^\+/{printf ("%s%s\n", $0,a);next}1' file
@F7##########0/1
C4CTA6GCAAC56G67CTCA99C
+F7##########0/1
b[[WZ56W]87X9HBB
@44FC6%%%%&&&&&&&1UP1
GTS4HY2IOMD3FCCA8DFLLLTG
+44FC6%%%%&&&&&&&1UP1
]]^4YY23ZV\6`a8`^9^a
```

#### Test for `sed`:

You can use `-i` option for making changes in place. The following is just for demo so that you can see the output.

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] sed '/^@/{h};/^\+/{x;s/\(.\)\(.*\)/+\2/}' file
@F7##########0/1
C4CTA6GCAAC56G67CTCA99C
+F7##########0/1
b[[WZ56W]87X9HBB
@44FC6%%%%&&&&&&&1UP1
GTS4HY2IOMD3FCCA8DFLLLTG
+44FC6%%%%&&&&&&&1UP1
]]^4YY23ZV\6`a8`^9^a
```

Comment: That line of `sed` is exactly what I was looking for originally when I tried using `sed`. However, I gave up on `sed` when I couldn't match or replace `\n`. It looks like complicated regex, would you mind explaining it for me?

Comment: That is really neat! An A+ explanation too. Thanks!

Comment: Well done. In the sed solution `/^\+/` threw me for a moment as without the `-r` switch `+` is not special and normally need not be escaped. However if it is escaped it means `1 or more of the preceeding character or subexpression` but in perverse logic as the `^` is place marker and not a character it reverts to a `+` character.

Answer (score 2):

My apologies. I read your question more carefully and see that you want to process your file line by line. This one-liner will achieve that

```
perl -pe "$dat = $1 if /^\@(.+)/; s/^\+/+$dat/;" infile
```

Answer (score 0):

The program below appears to do what you need

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = <<'STR';
@F7##########0/1
C4CTA6GCAAC56G67CTCA99C
+
b[[WZ56W]87X9HBB
@44FC6%%%%&&&&&&&1UP1
GTS4HY2IOMD3FCCA8DFLLLTG
+
]]^4YY23ZV\6`a8`^9^a
STR

$str =~ s/^@(.+?)$(.+?)^\+/\@$1$2+$1/gms;

print $str;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
@F7##########0/1
C4CTA6GCAAC56G67CTCA99C
+F7##########0/1
b[[WZ56W]87X9HBB
@44FC6%%%%&&&&&&&1UP1
GTS4HY2IOMD3FCCA8DFLLLTG
+44FC6%%%%&&&&&&&1UP1
]]^4YY23ZV\6`a8`^9^a
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/^@/h;/^+/{G;s/\n@//}' file
@F7##########0/1
C4CTA6GCAAC56G67CTCA99C
+F7##########0/1
b[[WZ56W]87X9HBB
@44FC6%%%%&&&&&&&1UP1
GTS4HY2IOMD3FCCA8DFLLLTG
+44FC6%%%%&&&&&&&1UP1
]]^4YY23ZV\6`a8`^9^a
```